# how to add layers in a sequential model for given computational graph

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[1[computational graph]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHlgD.png)i am working on text classification problem using CNN with glove word imbedding

how can i add 3 conv1D layers in a model and then concatenate output to apply maxpooling. it would be great if someone can help me with basic structure. Thanks

Comment: Sequential models are limited for one input and one output. Instead you may use functional api.

Comment: i am kinda new to TF keras can you help me with structure for functional api




input=Input(shape=(1050,),dtype='int64')
embedding =Embedding(5000,300,weights=[matrix],trainable=False)(input)
c1=Conv1D(350,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu')(embedding)
c2=Conv1D(350,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu')(embedding)
c3=Conv1D(350,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu')(embedding)
inter_1=(Concatenate([c1,c2,c3]))
x=MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(inter_1)




this is what iam doing , it says i cant use concatenated layers for input to my maxpooling layer

Comment: Please add what you have done so far with codes, to your question, not comments. Thank you.